# Normalize dataset so that median is 0.5

Tags: python, math, scikit-learn, scipy

I have a dataset of positive integers that I want to scale so that the output range is `[0.0,1.0]` and the median maps to `0.5`.

1. Is this possible to do at all?
2. If so, how can I do it in Python using `scipy` or `sklearn`?

Comment: If you enter "normalize data" into your browser's search window, you will get many useful references -- more than we can -- or should -- provide here.

Answer (score 0):

This is mathematically impossible to do in general with a linear scale plus translation (that is `x[i] = a*x[i] + b`).

Comment: Actually, there is something called Normalized Rank, which could give an output in the range of [0.0, 1.0] such the median is always 0.5. Refer [here](https://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/Similarity/Normalized-Rank.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling the data to the [0,1] interval is easy. It should be x=(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x).

If you just wanted the data to have a median of 0.5 without the [0,1] requirement, you could do x = 0.5*x/median(x).

But if you want both to be true, it can't be done with scaling.